# Bigquery extract from timestamp failing

Tags: google-bigquery

When running the following query:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP '2018-07-09T02:40:23.652Z' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern')
```

it returns intended result: 22

However when running:

```
SELECT start_ts, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_MICROS(CAST(1000000 * start_ts AS INT64)) AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') as calc 
    from SOME_CALCS
```

Throws an error:

> Syntax error: Expected ")" or keyword AT but got identifier
>   "TIMESTAMP_MICROS" at [1:46]

Where all I've done is replace the string with TIMESTAMP_MICROS.

Comment: Doesn't work at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just don't need a keyword `timestamp` in your code

```
select
    extract(
        hour from
        timestamp_micros(
            cast(1563456789.012345 * 1000000 as int64)
        ) at time zone 'US/Eastern')
```

`timestamp_micros` already returns timestamp object for you: 
[timestamp_micros](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_micros)

Answer (score 0):

You should use (assuming your start_ts is of the format: 1563026408.17193) for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT start_ts, 
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(CAST(1000000 * start_ts AS INT64)), 'US/Eastern')) as calc
FROM SOME_CALCS
```